# Exception.ToString() path

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm using log4net to maintain an exceptions log of an application. I realized that the log info shows the file path of the development environment even thought it's not published in the same machine and location.

e.g.:

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at MyProjectNamespace.MyProject.MyPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in **C:\Users\MySolutionFolder**\TestPage.aspx.cs:line 47}

I've also realized that the Exception.ToString() is the problem, I've published a test page that throwed the exception in the screen and it also brought the development enviroment's path.

I'd like to know how to set up the application to display the location where the application is hosted.

Comment: Not sure what the point might be.  Surely you are going to fix the bug on the machine that has this source code?  You see whatever was recorded in the .pdb file when the app was built.

Comment: Thank's for the tip! I didn't know it occurred because of the .PDB files! Once I deleted them from the server, the log stopped showing the location, which already helped me!

Comment: Hans Passant is there a way to omit the location info but keep the line number when logging the exceptions with the .PDB files?

Answer (score 0):

Is your source code actually hosted? If not, then the message is simply telling you where your application *used* to be located.

Comment: The application was published local in my machine, but it's hosted in a webserver. I've tried to find a configuration key in the web.config but found nothing that could lead to the error.